# Fill odd even react in canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

How can I fill a grid with alternating colors, odd cells with one color and even cells with another color.

Currently i'm creating a grid using this code:

```
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
    columns = 6,
    rows = 4,
    w, h, tileWidth, tileHeight;
    console.log(canvas);

canvas.onresize = calcSize;
canvas.onmousemove = highlight;
```

Here is the code, currently only mouse hover activates background colors.

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/q5j3Q/)

Comment: @epoch why difficult? he wants something like a chess board and he wants to fill one square of the grid in red another in black(for example)) then one in red, another in black and so on and on in chess order

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you want a chessboard like style (odd/even), you can do something like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
     for (var u = 0; u < columns; u++) {
        ctx.fillStyle = (i + u) % 2 == 0 ? '#eee' : '#aaa';
        ctx.fillRect(u * tileWidth, i * tileHeight, tileWidth, tileHeight);
     }
}
```

Here is the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/epoch/Lav0mqy2/). <sup>(with some additional fixes)</sup>